# How to manage jwt authentication on symfony 3

Tags: jwt, symfony

I'm making REST backend in symfony3. One of specification in my project is to use JWT authentication.

Is there a bundle that supports that? Or/how to do it by my own.

I need simple solution that generates me token and secure few of my controller actions.

I saw https://github.com/auth0/jwt-auth-bundle and https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle. Does anyone work with this? I understand that LexikJWT is for Symfony2, what does not solve the case.

I would be grateful for any ideas how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

We develop a REST API with authentication JWT in SF2.
We do not wish to use the bundle Lexik because it was overkill.
We used the library: https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt .
We have a controller that checks the token, which extends the functional controllers.

Answer (score 0):

**Update - 2k19**, [LexikJWTAuthBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) works in Symfony 3.x, 4.x, 5.x. 
The official docs explain you very well on how to integrate it with Symfony.

Here are 2 resources/tutorials that explain the same in more detail.

- **https://digitalfortress.tech/php/jwt-authentication-with-symfony/**
- https://medium.com/@joeymasip/how-to-create-an-api-with-symfony-4-and-jwt-b2334a8fbec2